# Delegate Pattern in React - how to achieve it?

Tags: reactjs

I'm mostly a C++ developer and I'm having a hard time understanding how can I create something as a 'Delegate' in React.

What I wanna achieve: Pass a custom component to a Table Component that has the required code to edit the data on a table cell correctly.

on my mainApp:

```
<TableComponent 
    headerData=["first", "second", "third"]
    rowEditDelegates=[<input/>, <button></button>, <combobox/>]
/>
```

The code is much shorter for brievety.

```
class TableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            editDelegates = this.props.rowEditDelegates;
            displayEditors = false;
        }

        onEditToogled() {
             /* Here I have no idea how to get the editDelegates
               and pass data to it. */
             setState({displayEditors : true});
        }
    }

    render() {
        let row = null;
        if(this.state.displayEditors) {
           row = this.state.editDelegates.map((item) => <td> {item} </td>)
        } else {
           row = this.props.bodyData.map((item) => <td> {item} </td>)
        }
    }
};
```

I cannot access the delegate's methods because it's a rendered component, and I didn't understand how to work with a component "pointer" (I don't even know if it exists), maybe my problem needs a different mindset than a c++ programmer one.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options here:

1) Use [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) function:

```
onEditToogled() 
{
    setState({displayEditors : true});
}

render() 
{
    let row = null;
    if(this.state.displayEditors) 
    {
       row = this.state.editDelegates.map((item) => {
           var alteredElement = React.cloneElement(item, {className: "newPropertyValue"});
           return (<td> {alteredElement} </td>);
       });
    }
    else
    {
       row = this.props.bodyData.map((item) => <td> {item} </td>)
    }
}
```

2) Change the way how you pass the editor components, for example:

```
<TableComponent 
    headerData=["first", "second", "third"]
    rowEditDelegates=[(props) => <input {...props}/>, (props) => <button {...props}/>, (props) => <combobox {...props}/>]
/>
```

And later:

```
render() {
    let row = null;
    if(this.state.displayEditors) {
       row = this.state.editDelegates.map((itemFunc) => <td> {itemFunc({className: "newPropertyValue"})} </td>)
    } else {
       row = this.props.bodyData.map((itemFunc) => <td> {itemFunc()} </td>)
    }
}
```

As a side note.

I do not think there is a need for you to copy and keep your "delegates" in state. They are unlikely to change? If so - just leave them in props.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm thinkering here to see how to apply this.